# How to use FindWindow when we programmatically get the name of the application

Tags: c#, string

I'm quite a newbie and maybe I don't use method correctly at all. 
I want to start different acquisitions software at the same time.

For that I have a foreground application window, which simulates a spacebar tap or simulate a `Mouseclick` when pressing a "play button". I then minimize it,  and bring another application into the foreground and do the same. It's actually very fast and works great.

But I have an issue with one piece of software. Its name changes a lot (it takes the name of the folder into, that the video is saved.

To find the name of this application at the time, I use `enumwindow` and get it with a filter.

But here's my issue the name of the application is saved as a `string`.

With the foreground application, I have to find it with `FindWindow` and i have to put into quote marks the name of the application. Of course if I put my `string` into quote marks it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
//[Lot of Dllimport]
public void namewindow()
{
    string[] strWindowsTitles = GetDesktopWindowsTitles();
    //all the name of open applications
    foreach (string strTitle in strWindowsTitles)
    {
        if (strTitle.Contains("Motive"))
        {
            string Motive = strTitle;
            //Here if I put a MessageBox.Show(Motive),
            //I have a name like:
            //Motive:Body 1.10.0 Beta 1 (C:\Users\Public\Documents\OptiTrack\
        }
    }
}

public void openwindow()
{
    IntPtr splashwindow = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Motive");
    FindWindow;
    SetForegroundWindow(splashwindow);
    ShowWindowAsync(splashwindow, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

This work perfectly fine with

```
IntPtr splashwindow = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Kinovea");
FindWindow;
SetForegroundWindow(splashwindow);
ShowWindowAsync(splashwindow, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

for example.

So it works fine if I put the name of the application between the quotes, but if I put my `string` between the quotes, nothing happens. Have you get any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: On another note, please don't post the same question twice, instead you can edit your original question and try to improve upon it. If it's a completely new question, feel free to ask, but posting the same thing twice, even if reworded is generally frowned upon

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you are trying to do, but I would posit that it makes more sense to find the window *once* by name, and thereafter store the handle to that window (`HWND`) for subsequent use. The app can change a window's name all it wants, but it can't change the window handle without destroying and recreating the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going on what [you also posted in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522267/findwindow-issue-with-quote-mark), I feel your code should be this instead:

```
public string nameWindow(string searchFor)
{
    string[] strWindowsTitles = GetDesktopWindowsTitles();
    //all the names of open applications
    foreach (string strTitle in strWindowsTitles)
    {
        if (strTitle.Contains(searchFor))
        {
            return strTitle;
        }
    }
    else
        return null;
}
public void openwindow()
{
    string motiveWindow = nameWindow("Motive");
    if (motiveWindow != null){
        IntPtr splashwindow = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, motiveWindow);
        //FindWindow;//Not sure what this does?
        SetForegroundWindow(splashwindow);
        ShowWindowAsync(splashwindow, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    }
}
```

That changes it so your method of `nameWindow()` will locate a window (The first one it comes across) with the word you have passed, to the method, in the variable of `searchFor`. In this case, "Motive". Then, if the variable `motiveWindow` is not null (So a window has been found), it will run your expected code and display the window.

You need to be careful about how you set the variables and what returns what. At the moment your `nameWindow()` doesn't seem to be doing much, possibly setting a variable called 'Motive', which I've not seen declared, but you then never use that variable elsewhere. Here, we're returning a variable and acting upon the data returned. You may find you want to make your `openWindow()` method take a variable, attempt to open a window of the same name, if none is found, then it calls the method `nameWindow()` and searches for it. That way you can work with both scenarios you have presented.

Comment: Thank you !! I actually misunderstood the origin of my issue, nothing to do with quote mark obvisouly... It works that way, cheers!