# FindWindow issue with quote mark

Tags: c#

I am trying to make my program find a window programmatically, for that I use `findwindow` by caption.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

IntPtr splashwindow = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero,
    "Motive:Body 1.10.0 Beta 1 (C:\Users\Public\Documents\OptiTrack\)" )
```

It works perfectly fine, however I need to do

```
string Motive = "Motive:Body 1.10.0 Beta 1 (C:\Users\Public\Documents\OptiTrack\)"
```

and put it into the function

```
IntPtr splashwindow = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero , "Motive" )
```

obviously it can't work because `FindWindowByCaption` method is looking for a program named "Motive".
So How can I "skip" the quote mark to make `FindWindowByCaption` recognizes the string?

Heres's my code

```
public void getwindow()
{
    string[] strWindowsTitles = GetDesktopWindowsTitles();
    string Motive;
    foreach (string strTitle in strWindowsTitles)
    {
        if (strTitle.Contains("Motive"))
        {
            Motive = strTitle;
            MessageBox.Show(Motive); 
            // this shows me Motive:Body 1.10.0 Beta 1
            //(C:\Users\Public\Documents\OptiTrack\)
        }
    }
    IntPtr splashwindow = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero , Motive );          
}
```

I get the name of all of the opened applications via `enumwindow` (this part of the code is quite long and works fine) put it into `strWindowTitles` & get the one I need with the filter.

Comment: Hmm.. call it like this `FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, Motive)` (`Motive` is variable now) or what is the problem?

Comment: Error it says "Use of unassigned local variable 'Motive'"

Comment: Can you show a bit more of code? I was thinking you define `Motive` just before method call. It seems you don't.

Comment: Your code should go in this order: `string motive = "Motive:Body 1.10.0 Beta 1 (C:\Users\Public\Documents\OptiTrack\)"; FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, motive);`

Make sure you are declaring your `motive` variable before you call the method `FindWindowByCaption`

Comment: BTW, the reason the method `IntPtr splashwindow = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero , "Motive");` doesn't work, isn't due to the quotes, it's searching for a string literal that has the value **Motive**, not your variable that you declared called `Motive`. C# assumes that when you surround text with double quotes ("), it's a string, never a variable

Comment: If you need window with that exact title, then specify it `FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "ThatExactTitle")`, you don't need variable. To actually put variable inside string you can use `variable.ToString()` or *interpolated string* `$"{variable}"`. But I am afraid the problem is bigger than that. Can you explain why do you need variable? To find window with different titles? How different? Give us examples.

Comment: in this order it works fine actually, but i need to get it via foreach (string strTitle in strWindowsTitles) etc etc 
What is the issue then?! Isn't My variable declaring before i call the method FindWindowbyCaption ?! sorry i m very new...

Comment: heres my issue explained differently
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37479686/how-to-use-findwindow-when-we-programmatically-get-the-name-of-the-application

Comment: Are you attempting to find all windows that contains the title "Motive"? At the moment, you'll only locate the last one in the list. What happens when you put a breakpoint at the line of `IntPtr splashwindow = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero , Motive );`, what is your object of `Motive` set to at that point? What are you doing with the object `splashwindow` after you have set it with your `FindWindowByCaption()` method?

Comment: I've answered your other question, I've voted this one to be closed as they are very similar